# Errors in flutter build apk

Tags: flutter, dart

I have same errors when use `flutter build apk`.

I want create APK for just install in android device not for publish on google play.
can i use any code in terminal to fix this issue?

Errors:

```
     FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not delete old \build\app\reports\lint-results-release-fatal.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                       7.6s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

flutter doctor - v :

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1082], locale ar-IQ)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
edition (version 1.33.1)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

How i can fix this errors.

Thanks for All

Comment: did you had a solution bro ?

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problems of licenses enter in the terminal

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```